# c# decimal to binary wrong output

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie in C# and I was trying to convert decimal numbers to binary but the output is wrong. I want to know what's wrong with it. For example, I gave input "69" value. The output was "11" instead of "1000101".

```
double input = Convert.ToDouble(Console.Readline());
double i;
double newNumber = 0;

for (i = Int32.MaxValue; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (input >= Math.Pow(2, i))
    {
        newNumber = input - Math.Pow(2, i);
        Console.Write("1");
        break;
    }
}

for (i -= i; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (newNumber >= Math.Pow(2, i))
    {
        newNumber = newNumber - Math.Pow(2, i);
        Console.Write("1");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("0");
    }
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What do you think `i -= i` does and why do you think it's the right way to start your second loop? There are simpler ways to write `i=0` if that's what you want to do.

Comment: What do you mean `binary` in the first place? `decimal` is a floating point number and its binary representation is different from integers. You can use [decimal.GetBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits?view=net-7.0) to get the bits.  What you posted looks like an attempt to calculate the integral bits only - in which case you could use [BitConverter.GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-7.0) to get the actual bytes and construct a BitArray

Comment: Hey Damien! In my first loop (assuming the input was 69) i was equal to 6. Since I don't want the second loop to check 6 again and didn't want to give i "0" value (because it should keep checking powers of 2 from 5) I wrote "i -= i".

Comment: But `i -= i` *does* assign it the value `0`, but in a convoluted way. Perhaps you intended to subtract *1* instead of `i`?

Comment: I thought defining i out of the loop could keep it's value. You said when I write i -= i it does assign it the value 0. So how do I do it without i getting 0 value?

Comment: It does keep it's value, right up until you write `i -= i`, which is "Take the value of the `i` variable, subtract the value of the `i` variable from that and assign the value back to the `i` variable". Which always subtracts a number from itself and, outside of rare cases, that always produces 0.

Comment: Do you have *integer values* only (e.g. `69`) or it's possible to have *floating point* values (e.g. `3.14159`)?

Comment: A simple `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(input, 2));` might do it. For integers i should say.

Comment: If I don't write "i -= i" it should still be "6" right? I can write "i--;" between two loops to make it's value "5" but then what am I supposed to write in here: "for (here; i >= 0, i--)

Comment: You could write `i--` in "here", rather than between the loops. Why do you think you couldn't? Or if you want to keep the `i--` outside of the loop, you don't have to put *anything* in "here". `for(;i>=0;i--)` is a well formed `for`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know I could do that... Thanks a lot ^^ When the error said " expecting ; " I didn't know where to put it :')

Comment: You compute `Math.Pow(2, i)` when `i` starts from `Int32.MaxValue ~ 2e9`? It'll  be an *inifinity*

Comment: @idkhowtocode i like that people try to help you understanding your code and not only show how its done right, but did you actually try to debug your own code? You seems to have expectation what you code does (and how it does it). But obviously it does not do that so debug your code and check your expectations if they are meet. There is more to learn for you then listening to advices given here by that.

Comment: @Ralf I'm in a position where I can't use visual studio to run my code so I'm using an online compiler that's why I couldn't use a breakpoint to see what's wrong. I agree with you on that. last time I asked a question on here everyone said that I should change it with a whole different code and this time people helped me understand what was wrong with my own code I appreciate it ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost works, just replace `i -= i` with `i -= 1` on your second loop, since you already processed `i`, you want to start 1 position lower.

Note:
Although it works, this strategy is a bit off, since it loops through `int.MaxValue`. I would suggest to find another way to get the most significant bit. You could use `Log2(input)` to get your starting index.

Here is a bit shortened version of yours.

```
double input = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

if (input == 0)
{
    Console.Write("0");
    return;
}

for (int i = (int)Math.Log2(input); i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (input >= Math.Pow(2, i))
    {
        input -= Math.Pow(2, i);
        Console.Write("1");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("0");
    }
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm not used to writing stuff like "-=" if I have written" i = i - i" I would've seen my mistake. I should pay more attention ^^.  About Log2(input) I got this error " error CS0117: 'Math' does not contain a definition for 'Log2' " maybe it's because I'm trying it on an online compiler. I'll try it again as soon as I can in visual studio.

Comment: `Math2()` is added in .NET Core 3 and later. In earlier versions you can use `Math.Log(input, 2)`

Comment: It worked. Tysm ^^

Answer (score 0):

There is a short way... You can use

> Convert.ToString(numberInBase10, targetBase)

Here is an example:

```
int[] numbersBase10 = { 7, 10, 23, 45, 69, 99 };

foreach (int number in numbersBase10)
{
    string numberBase2 = Convert.ToString(number, 2);
    Console.WriteLine($"{number} => {numberBase2}");
}
```

The output is:

```
7 => 111
10 => 1010
23 => 10111
45 => 101101
69 => 1000101
99 => 1100011
```

Comment: I didn't get the last line. Could you be so kind to explain what " $"{number} => {numberBase2}" " does?

Comment: It's just a type of writing string. The main part is "Convert.Tostring()" for you. for example you asked for 69 in base 2. The ansver is this:
"string result = Convert.ToString(69, 2);"

Comment: Okayyy thank you for the help ^^